# Excel VBA: Autorun when Create New Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, autorun

I want to autorun a macro whenever I create a new worksheet in a workbook.  Below is what I tried:

```
    Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet()
        Call Macro1
    End Sub

    Sub Macro1()
        ...
        ...
    End Sub
```

Turns out nothing happened. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have put them under the wrong place.

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh as Object)
    Call Macro1
End Sub
```

should be put under **ThisWorkBook** while

```
Sub Macro1()
    ...
    ...
End Sub
```

should be put under **Modules**

Comment: Thanks a lot!  FYI, the expression of NewSheet is .NewSheet(Sh).  I found it out from microsoft.com when my code failed to work.  Below is an example from the website:

Comment: Thanks a lot!  FYI, the expression of NewSheet is .NewSheet(Sh).  I found it out from microsoft.com when my code failed to work.  Please refer the link here: [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821246.aspx)

Comment: yea I know..I just simply copy your code :P

I usually select the event from the drop down list